# need list of best automation test tool for ios apps

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

I am working on ios app testing. I need to know what are all the test tools available for functional testing and which is the best among them.

I also heard many developers using the tool named fonemonkey is that a good one ? or please suggest me a good too which you guys use for your apps.

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) by Gorilla Logic. They have a lot of nice features for getting started such as recording directly on the device. They are also able to perform faceless GUI tests for instance when running in a Continuous Integration environment such as Jenkins or similar.

You might also want to check out [Keep It Functional](https://github.com/square/KIF) (or KIF) which have recently been made available as an open source project on GitHub. It's a fairly new project so it doesn't (yet) provide all the same features as FoneMonkey. For instance it's currently lacking recording so you will have to write your test scenarios from scratch.

Comment: FoneMonkey is now MonkeyTalk and it can be found here:https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SeeTest](http://experitest.com) from Experitest. It's very easy to work with and support script exprot to code environment. I'm personlay using Python.